# RIA Services DomainService query with EF Projection that calls method and still allows composable paging/sorting

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, linq, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

Here's an interesting problem that I hope someone can lend a hand with.

I have a DomainService class with the following query:

```
    [Query]
    public IEnumerable<BatchResult> GetBatchResults(int batchId)
    {
        return ObjectContext.BatchQueries
            .Include("BatchTCResults")
            .Include("BatchANFResults")
            .Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId)
            .Where(x => x.BatchTCResults.Any() || x.BatchANFResults.Any())
            .ToArray() // enumerate because projection calls a method that EF will poop it's pants on
            .Select(x => new BatchResult
            {
                BatchQueryId = x.Id,
                Route = x.Routing,
                Account = x.Account,
                Amount = x.Amount,
                CheckNumber = x.CheckNumber,
                Severity = BatchResult.DetermineOverallSeverity(x)
            });
    }
```

This works BUT I really need the paging/sorting information passed from the Silverlight client to be applied before enumeration happens in the line calling `.ToArray()`

The client side is using the DomainDataSource Silverlight control.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is adding paging/sorting/filtering parameters to the method arguments list and adding corresponding LINQ query operators to your data context query in the service method. However, in this case you'll loose client-side `IQueryable` features. I mean, client's queries will reach only the application server, but won't get to the database. And you'll need some layer between the `DomainContext` and the UI: `DomainDataSource` is not likely to work.

Exposing the results of the query as `IQueryable` using `AsQueryable()` won't help since expression trees will be unconditionally compiled into code in order to execute your LINQ-to-Objects operators.

Somewhat harder option is using arguments as in first case together with writing your own `IQueryable` wrapper over the client-side query object. This wrapper would extract parameters from query expressions and pass them to the service as method arguments. Well, I'd only try this if I had enough spare time.

Another difficult way is doing analogous thing server-side. It's possible to get an `IQueryable` object that has the expression tree passed from client in a `DomainService`. You'll need to override the `DomainService.Query` method. Then you'll be able to extract part of the query expression that relates to paging/sorting, save it to a field and then apply to the database query. However, `Query` method is single for all methods in a given `DomainService`. Therefore, you'll probably end with a big table method that decides what to do for each of the service query methods. Needless to say, the service will become very difficult.

To conclude, I strongly recommend you the first option.